# Filters result in "Expression not valid" - Sharepoint 2013 API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

Here is the request:

```
https://sub.domain.com/Stores/CrisisMgmt/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('StoreClosures')/Items$select=StoreRegion
```

When I make a request without the filter, I get all this data just fine including the `StoreRegion`, but `select`, `filter`, etc always result in `expression not valid`.

Any ideas where to start troubleshooting? Worth mentioning even things as trivial as `$top=5` will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('StoreClosures')/Items?$select=StoreRegion

_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('StoreClosures')/Items?$select=StoreRegion&$top=5

_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('StoreClosures')/Items?$select=StoreRegion&$filter=<you  filter>
```

The issue is the missing `?` before the filter identifying the filter as a query parameter.

Comment: Yeah I did end up doing something like this in the end. Is this seriously the recommended route, though? That's so messy and involved.

Comment: Notice that the "?" is missing in your api request. Check the demos